# Why pad sentences while using RNNs pytorch

Tags: machine-learning, nlp

Why do we pad sentences to max length of all the sentences in the batch before feeding in RNNs (like LSTM)?

Comment: To have a consistent length of texts. More than pad sentences, it would be referred to as padding sequences. Padding sequences is not specific to learning algorithm, it is kind of preprocessing technique before feeding data into any type of learning algorithm.

Comment: Machine learning algorithms usually don't do well with variable size input tensors so you then have two options - either chop all inputs to the length of the shortest input or pad them to the length of the longest one.